# vb.net rebind datagrid to display changes in vb.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, data-binding, datagridview, datasource

I have the following code that refreshes the datagrid in the form after the update is made to the database.  My question is why do I have to clear the datasource and then re-add it to get the changes to display.  I would think that the refresh method would do this, but I can't seem to get that to work.  Is there a more efficient way to refresh the datagrid rather than resetting the datasource?

```
Public Sub addPlan(ByVal planname, ByVal plannumber)
    Dim planinfo As New changeDatabase(planname, plannumber, planAdapter)

    planinfo.addPlan()
    Form1.DataGridView1.EndEdit()

    Form1.DataGridView1.DataSource = ""
    Form1.DataGridView1.DataSource = planAdapter.GetData()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try creating an explicit `BindingSource` and assign a datasource to it, then set the `DataGridView`’s DataSource property to the BindingSource instance.

The `BindingSource` object’s `ResetBinding` method will cause the `DataGridView` to reread all the items in the list and refresh all displayed values.

```
Dim bindingSource As BindingSource
bindingSource = New BindingSource()
bindingSource.DataSource = planAdapter.GetData()
Form1.DataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource

bindingSource.ResetBindings(false)
```

Note: Passing false means that only values have changed in the original datasource, true means that the schema of the data has changed.

Answer (score 1):

The code below shows a way to set this up that works:

```
Protected WithEvents myWordClueList As WordClueList
Protected gridBindingSource As BindingSource

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    myWordClueList = New WordClueList()

    myWordClueList.Add(New WordCluePair With {.Word = "Eden", .Clue = "First garden"})
    myWordClueList.Add(New WordCluePair With {.Word = "Fears", .Clue = "Aggregate of negative emotions"})

    ' Instantiate a binding source for the GridView
    gridBindingSource = New BindingSource With {.DataSource = myWordClueList}
    WordClueGrid.DataSource = gridBindingSource

End Sub
```

The trick is to use a Binding Source object.

To update the GridView when changes are made to the DataSource, call the ResetBindings method of your BindingSource object.

```
        myWordClueList.OrderBy(Function(pairRow As WordCluePair) pairRow)
        gridBindingSource.ResetBindings(False)
```